# jQuery ListView control not available in jQuery UI? For use with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, asp.net-mvc-3

I have been checking the jQuery UI for a listview control and one doesn't seem to exist.

Of course I can't use the asp.net control because I am using MVC.

Is there an alternative?  Or another recommended plugin?

There doesn't seem to be any available unless I am missing something.

Comment: Could you tell us how you intended to use the control? We could then suggest alternatives.

Comment: Sure, i inttend to use it with column headers to show filenames. It needs to function like the list view control in Windows i.e. Change view from list view, icon view. Also each row i need the ability to add an icon in column 1. What would be great is if i could do a GROUP by as well... on the list view similar to how the My Computer displays items i.e. grouped by Hard Disks and then Removable Disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Web Grid](http://weblogs.asp.net/andrebaltieri/archive/2010/11/01/asp-net-mvc-3-working-with-webgrid.aspx) will work for your problem. You could also just render a table with rows in it, iterating over the model. I usually go with the latter since I have complete control over how and what gets rendered.